# Unable to install Wine - list of sources could not be read

Tags: wine, uninstall, mono

I tried to get Wine (because I saw that I can't use `.exe` files in Ubuntu) but I didn't know about `sudo add-others...`

I randomly walked to some kind of Mono. I entered it and it didn't continue for some reason.

Later, when I downloaded Wine, it reported something when I entered `sudo`. At the end, it says Mono-official. However, now it says:

```
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-offical-stable.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I can't delete (remove) it. I need help removing it because I need to reinstall Ubuntu again.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to delete the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-offical-stable.list` it should be possible to fix this, but if you're not experienced, it will be easier to delete the file.

Open up a terminal, by using the windows key (assuming you have one) and typing `terminal`

In the terminal, you will need to type:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-offical-stable.list
```

After you have deleted the file, you should be able to:

```
sudo apt update
```

and you should not get errors.

Comment: dude thx so much it maybe worked but do i need to ignore this message
W: Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq-org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/groovy/InRelease  Could not resolve 'dl.winehq-org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Looks like you have an old wine repository set up (that's not working). Since Ubuntu has a decent version if wine in it, it should be safe to ignore, but if I were you, I'd get rid of that file too, but you should be able to do that through the software update graphical tool